# IntelliJ Idea remote debugger hangs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

When I use remote debugger in IntelliJ to debug a Java application on server, it stops on breakpoints successfully but when I try to evaluate any expressions or variables it hangs and shows nothing (usually with "collecting data" message). From that point I can't even continue stepping through code anymore. I have to click resume so it at least runs, but it will never stop at other breakpoints too until I restart the debug session and usually even the Java application being debugged.

I can step through the code after stopping on breakpoint, also I see the variables in the debugger panel, it only starts to behave weirdly when I try to evaluate an expression or add a watcher. Then it stops working and restart of the debugger and the app is needed.

Did anybody experience something similar? Is it IntelliJ or server problem?

(sorry this is so vaguely described, but I have no idea what to share or what the problem might be)

Comment: Can you specify which version of IntelliJ you are using. Also Community or Professionl? With IntelliJ 16, I've noticed that you don't usually need to evaluate or watch expressions, IntelliJ highlights the values of variables till the point of current execution of your breakpoint. So am not sure why you should see that.

Comment: 2016 professional. Well, sometimes, I need to evaluate more than what is in the executed code to debug errors (or change the values to simulate something)

Comment: It probably depends on what your trying to debug and evaluate. So unless there is any more information provided I cant help am afraid.

I would suggest adding in more information about what your trying to debug, and the server and its version and if there's any information you can extract from the app logs if any.

Comment: This happens to me anytime I use the debugger to hit any breakpoint...

Comment: I think I experience similar thing. When app just runs (even in debug mode) without breakpoints it goes fast. However when you stop on breakpoint frames and variables are slowly resolved. By resolved I mean slowly appearing frames and slowly disappearing "collecting data" messages next to vaiables. I do not know how long have you waited for evaluation, but in my case finally control gets back to you with a result. So it does not hang. It is just terribly slow... and it probably depends on complexity of your code, amount of variables, etc... Slow connection also does not help here.

Comment: slowness or resolving was always slow, but that is fine, it least it works and shows up at some point. But this totally disables and hangs the debugger when I evaluate something :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression evaluation during remote debug need more data to be sync then the other operations ( breakpoints add/remove, step managements ecc ).
So this kind of issue should be just related to:

- a **slow connection**
- an **huge complexity and amount of data involved into the operation to execute** in the remote server

Comment: How slow can it be? I've let the evaluation loading for a couple of minutes before I gave up. So, in the end, I gave up on evaluation on remote debug sessions as it was unbearable.

Comment: I also experienced a 15 minute wait with a very slow connection where the result of the evaluation expression was a map containing a lot of very huge objects!